# MS Access import image into table

Tags: sql-server, database, image, ms-access, ole

In MS Access I'd like to be able to search for an image, or images, on the system and then save them into OLE fields in tables that are linked to an SQL server.

Having a preview in the form would be ideal as well.

This seems like a simple task but honestly I've given up after hours of searching. 
And as I'm storing the images as Varbinary(MAX) in an SQL database, no **I don't want to just store a link to the images.**

Answer (score 1):

After setting an image field, I attached this to a button:

```vb
Private Sub CommandOpenPicture_Click()
     Dim strFilter As String
     Dim strInputFileName As String

     strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, "JPEG Files (*.jpg, *.jpeg)", "*.jpg;*.jpeg")
     strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, "bmp Files (*.bmp)", "*.bmp")
     strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, "all Files (*.*)", "*.*")

     strInputFileName = ahtCommonFileOpenSave( _
                             Filter:=strFilter, _
                             OpenFile:=True, _
                             DialogTitle:="Choose an image file...", _
                             Flags:=ahtOFN_HIDEREADONLY)

     If Len(strInputFileName) > 0 Then
         ' Do something with the selected file
        imgDamPic.Picture = strInputFileName
        Me.DamsPhoto.Value = imgDamPic.Picture
        file_path.Value = strInputFileName
                'Put SQL Insert Statement or DAO here

      Else
         'No file chosen, or user canceled
      End If
End Sub
```